# создать realtions с помощью цикла в Yii2

Tags: yii2, relation

у меня есть model LangModuleText,оно связано с Language.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот что сгенерировало Gii генератор.

```
public function getLang()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Language::className(), ['id' => 'lang_id']);
    }
```

я хочу взять все языки которые находятся в таблице Language и с помощью цикла и получить что то вроде этого

```
public function getLang_russian()
        {
          ....
        }
public function getLang_english()
        {
          ....
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

В модели `Language`:

```
public function getLangModuleTexts()
{
    return $this->hasMany(LangModuleText::className(), ['lang_id' => '']);
}
```

В контроллере:

```
$languages = Language::find()->with('langModuleTexts')->all();
```

Во вьюшке:

```
<?php foreach ($languages as $language) {
    echo "<h3>{$language->name}</h3>";
    foreach ($language->langModuleTexts as $text) {
        echo $text->text . '<br>';
    }
} ?>
```

Comment: мне конкретно нужен так как я описал

Comment: @HarutAl поконкретнее напишите, а то не совсем понятно. Приведите пример какие данные хранятся в таблицах